# How do I remove linebreaks within bibliography items?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

As my institution does not have an official template, I am using one that has been passed from person to person accreting commands as it goes along, though it was originally based on the [memoir style](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/).  The bibliography, for reasons that I don't understand, is currently formatted with excessive line breaks as shown:

[image: bibliography with line breaks]

I would like these line breaks removed, so that the entry flows continously on the same line.

The sections that definitely refer to the bibliography are:

```
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,sorting=nyt,urldate=long]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{'My Library.bib'}
```

and:

```
\section{Bibliography}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```

I can see nothing obvious there though, so it seems the problem is somewhere else in the 290 odd lines of LaTeX commands which I've uploaded to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/twSD01Gv).

I've read the relevant sections of the [memoir manual](https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) and tried adding `\setlength{\bibitemsep}{-\parsep}`, but this didn't seem to do anything.  Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Memoir documentation, you need to remove the `openbib` option in the `\documentclass` command.

Comment: Even though `memoir`'s `openbib` implementation only affects the classical `thebibliography` environment, `biblatex` also catches the `openbib` option and executes its `block=par` option, which leads to the output shown in the question.